# Powershell GUI. Изменение размера изображения (уменьшение, увеличение размера) и отображение его в $PictureBox

Tags: gui, powershell

Уважаемые пользователи форума, помогите пожалуйста, со следующим вопросом.
Я пытаюсь создать приложение с графическим интерфейсом в Powershell. Так как я новичок в программировании, то решился обратиться на форум за помощью.
Суть приложения заключается в вводе названия автомобиля в $InputBox.text и последующим отображении эмблемы автомобиля в $PictureBox.

Папка, в которой будут находиться изображения эмблем автомобилей, будет содержать много изображений разного размера.

При этом я хочу, чтобы программа отображала изображение в $PictureBox строго заданного размера: ширина 200, высота 110.

Если изображение больше по ширине - 200 и высоте - 110, я хочу, чтобы программа сжала его до размеров ширина - 200 и высота - 110 и отобразила изображение в $PictureBox.

Если изображение меньше ширины - 200 и высоты - 110, я хочу, чтобы программа растянула его до размеров ширина - 200 и высота - 110 и отобразила изображение в $PictureBox.

На скриншоте ниже показано, как программа выглядит сейчас.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
$form.Text = 'Сars'

############################################ Label ############################################

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label;
$Label.Text = "Cars emblem";
$Label.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(280,30);
$Label.ForeColor = "#3009f1"
$Label.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,14"
$Label.AutoSize = $true;
$form.Controls.Add($Label);

$Label_2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label;
$Label_2.Text = "Cars name";
$Label_2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10);
$Label_2.ForeColor = "#3009f1"
$Label_2.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,14"
$Label_2.AutoSize = $true;
$form.Controls.Add($Label_2);


############################################ InputBox #########################################

$InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,35) 
$InputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Sans Typewriter",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular) 
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox) 

############################################ PictureBox ############################################

$PictureBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PictureBox.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(270,70)
$PictureBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,110)
$PictureBox.BackColor = "#d2d2d2"
$form.Controls.add($PictureBox)

############################################ Function ############################################

function emblem { 
$image = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile('C:\cars\' + $InputBox.text + '.png')
$pictureBox.Image=$image
#$PictureBox.Load=$image
}


######################################################### Button #########################################################

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,90)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,80)
$Button.Text = "Display
picture"
$Button.BackColor = "#86bb6f"
$Button.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,14" 
$Button.Add_Click({emblem})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)


$form.ShowDialog()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поиграйтесь со свойством [SizeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)